# After updating Android Studio to 2.3 , my app works fine in device ( Nexus 5X) but it crash every time when i install the apk explicitly

Tags: android, android-studio

I did these things:
1) Clean the code and remove everything in /build folder.
2) Analyse AndroidManifest.xml file all activities have proper package name as suffix

**Multidex is already enabled**

These are the Error Logs i got every time.:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                       Process: com.android.packagename, PID: 25752
>                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application
>   com.android.packagename.BaseApplication:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.android.packagename.BaseApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file
>   "/data/app/com.android.packagename-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.packagename-1/lib/arm64,
>   /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
>                                                                           at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:802)
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5377)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.android.packagename.BaseApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file
>   "/data/app/com.android.packagename-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.packagename-1/lib/arm64,
>   /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
>                                                                           at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
>                                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:992)
>                                                                           at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:796)
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5377)
>
> ```
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                     at
> ```
>
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>
> ```
>                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
> ```

Comment: Please post your manifest file

Comment: Seems like a 'problem' from proguard to me. Check this answer maybe it can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32222740/2540578

Comment: This will works fine if i disable the InstaRun.

Answer (score 0):

Ok  try to install instant run for your target api

Or disable instant run from Android studio

More about [instant run](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#ir-limitations)

Answer (score 0):

Preferences->Build,Execution,Deployment->instant Run
then,
[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckucc.png)