# Exception: ClassNotFoundException & NoClassDefFoundError At Release Run Application

Tags: java, android, exception

When Run the application at Debug Mode Working successfully But when Run with Release Build Getting Below Error :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Laa$c;
       at com.marvhong.videoeffect.helper.MagicFilterFactory.filterType2Name + 105(MagicFilterFactory.java:105)
       at com.ui.audiovideoeditor.activity.TrimVideoActivity.initView + 265(TrimVideoActivity.java:265)
       at com.ui.audiovideoeditor.base.TrimmerBaseActivity.onCreate + 78(TrimmerBaseActivity.java:78)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate + 7032(Activity.java:7032)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate + 7023(Activity.java:7023)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate + 1236(Instrumentation.java:1236)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity + 2814(ActivityThread.java:2814)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity + 2943(ActivityThread.java:2943)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1630(ActivityThread.java:1630)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 106(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 164(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6626(ActivityThread.java:6626)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 438(RuntimeInit.java:438)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 811(ZygoteInit.java:811)


Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "aa$c" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.socialmediavideoadsmaker-TZFvA-VXiNm9BBp_hNHgGw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.socialmediavideoadsmaker-TZFvA-VXiNm9BBp_hNHgGw==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.socialmediavideoadsmaker-TZFvA-VXiNm9BBp_hNHgGw==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass + 125(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass + 379(ClassLoader.java:379)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass + 312(ClassLoader.java:312)
       at com.marvhong.videoeffect.helper.MagicFilterFactory.filterType2Name + 105(MagicFilterFactory.java:105)
       at com.ui.audiovideoeditor.activity.TrimVideoActivity.initView + 265(TrimVideoActivity.java:265)
       at com.ui.audiovideoeditor.base.TrimmerBaseActivity.onCreate + 78(TrimmerBaseActivity.java:78)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate + 7032(Activity.java:7032)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate + 7023(Activity.java:7023)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate + 1236(Instrumentation.java:1236)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity + 2814(ActivityThread.java:2814)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity + 2943(ActivityThread.java:2943)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1630(ActivityThread.java:1630)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 106(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 164(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6626(ActivityThread.java:6626)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 438(RuntimeInit.java:438)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 811(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

This Exception arrived from Crshlytics.
Video Effect Library i have used and in this Library Below are the Classes that NotFound in Release App:

```
public class MagicFilterFactory {

    /**
     * 视频滤镜效果
     * @return
     */
    public static GlFilter getFilter() {
        MagicFilterType filterType = ConfigUtils.getInstance().getMagicFilterType();
        return getFilter(filterType);
    }

    private static GlFilter getFilter(MagicFilterType filterType) {
        switch (filterType) {
            case NONE:
                return new GlFilter();
            case BILATERAL:
                return new GlBilateralFilter();
            case BOXBLUR:
                return new GlBoxBlurFilter();
            case BULGEDISTORTION:
                return new GlBulgeDistortionFilter();
            case CGACOLORSPACE:
                return new GlCGAColorspaceFilter();
            case GAUSSIANBLUR:
                return new GlGaussianBlurFilter();
            case GRAYSCALE:
                return new GlGrayScaleFilter();
            case HAZE:
                return new GlHazeFilter(0.5f, 0.3f);
            case INVERT:
                return new GlInvertFilter();
            case LUT:
                return new GlVignetteFilter();
            case MONOCHROME:
                return new GlMonochromeFilter();
            case SEPIA:
                return new SepiaEffect();
            case SHARPEN:
                return new GlSharpenFilter(3.f);
            case SPHEREREFRACTION:
                return new GlSphereRefractionFilter();
            case TONECURVE:
                return new GlToneCurveFilter();
            case VIGNETTE:
                return new GlVignetteFilter(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 0.85f);
            case BLACKANDWHITE:
                return new BlackAndWhiteEffect();
            case OVERLAY:
                return new OverlayEffect();
            case BARRELBLUR:
                return new BarrelBlurEffect();
            case POSTERIZE:
                return new PosterizeEffect();
            case CONTRAST:
                return new ContrastEffect();
            case GAMMA:
                return new GammaEffect();
            case CROSSPROCESS:
                return new CrossProcessEffect();
            case HUE:
                return new HueEffect();
            case TEMPERATURE:
                return new TemperatureEffect();
            case SKETCH:
                return new SketchEffect();
            default:
                return new GlFilter();
        }
    }

    public static int filterType2Name(MagicFilterType filterType) {
        switch (filterType) {
            case NONE:
                return R.string.filter_none;
            case INVERT:
                return R.string.filter_invert;
            case MONOCHROME:
                return R.string.filter_monochrome;
            case SEPIA:
                return R.string.filter_sepia;
            case GRAYSCALE:
                return R.string.filter_grayscale;
            case SHARPEN:
                return R.string.filter_sharpen;
            case SPHEREREFRACTION:
                return R.string.filter_sphererefraction;
            case BULGEDISTORTION:
                return R.string.filter_bulgedistortion;
            case CGACOLORSPACE:
                return R.string.filter_cgacolorspace;
            case HAZE:
                return R.string.filter_haze;
            case BILATERAL:
                return R.string.filter_bilateral;
            case TONECURVE:
                return R.string.filter_tonecurve;
            case VIGNETTE:
                return R.string.filter_vignette;
            case BLACKANDWHITE:
                return R.string.filter_blackandwhite;
            case OVERLAY:
                return R.string.filter_overlay;
            case BARRELBLUR:
                return R.string.filter_barrelblur;
            case POSTERIZE:
                return R.string.filter_posterize;
            case CONTRAST:
                return R.string.filter_contrast;
            case GAMMA:
                return R.string.filter_gamma;
            case CROSSPROCESS:
                return R.string.filter_crossprocess;
            case HUE:
                return R.string.filter_hue;
            case TEMPERATURE:
                return R.string.filter_temperature;
            case SKETCH:
                return R.string.filter_sketch;
            default:
                return R.string.filter_none;
        }
    }

    public static int filterType2Color(MagicFilterType filterType) {
        switch (filterType) {
            case NONE:
                return R.color.filter_category_greenish_dummy;

            default:
                return R.color.filter_category_greenish_normal;
        }
    }

    public static int filterType2Thumb(MagicFilterType filterType) {
        switch (filterType) {
            case NONE:
                return R.drawable.filter;
            case INVERT:
                return R.drawable.filter_invert;
            case SEPIA:
                return R.drawable.filter_sepia;
            case GRAYSCALE:
                return R.drawable.filter_grayscale;
            case CGACOLORSPACE:
                return R.drawable.filter_cgacolorspace;
            case BARRELBLUR:
                return R.drawable.filter_barrelblur;
            case BLACKANDWHITE:
                return R.drawable.filter_blackandwhite;
            case CONTRAST:
                return R.drawable.filter_contrast;
            case CROSSPROCESS:
                return R.drawable.filter_crossprocess;
            case GAMMA:
                return R.drawable.filter_gamma;
            case HUE:
                return R.drawable.filter_hue;
            case OVERLAY:
                return R.drawable.filter_overlay;
            case TEMPERATURE:
                return R.drawable.filter_temperature;
            default:
                return R.drawable.filter;
        }
    }
}
```

There is a Class that is not found at release time.

Also, I have applied below solution: 
1) [Android: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on the release APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547087/android-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-on-the-release-apk)
2) [Android: NoClassDefFoundError only on release build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222480/android-noclassdeffounderror-only-on-release-build)

Comment: Are you use Proguard ?

Comment: Try disabling proguard for your release build or you can add a rule in your proguard file to keep the Activity for which you are getting this error

Comment: Yes, i have used Proguard. @Abhay Koradiya

Comment: as @ShivamPokhriyal suggested, try after disabling proguard.

Comment: Also, I have disabled Proguard at release build and its working But i want to apply Proguard.

Comment: @axita.savani I think there is an issue in resource file fetching.

Comment: I have also same problem

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting you, Can you please explain in Detail? @VishrutMavani

Comment: Okay @axita.savani

Answer (score 0):

`minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` are very important in your build.gradle file if you want to decrease the size of generated apk for specific build types, ideally the ‘release’ type.

`minifyEnabled` shrinks code by deleting unused code and references.

`shrinkResources` on the other hand removes unused resource files from /res folder that are not referenced in the code.

you have to use this code

```
res = getResources().getIdentifier(filter_none, "string", getPackageName());
```

**instead of**

```
R.string.filter_none
```

Now, if you refer to a resource dynamically by using the [Resources.getIdentifier()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) the method then since unreferenced resources were removed, unexpected behavior will occur.

So to avoid this, when accessing resource dynamically, use this trick as explained in [Android User Guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) using this example

```
String name = String.format("img_%1d", angle + 1);
res = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Comment: Thank You, Bro I have applied solution and it's working

Comment: Yes, It's working @VishrutMavani Thank you So much.